# How to notify another component if profile pic is updated so that the changes gets reflected

Tags: angular

In the dashboard component I have a navbar which has user profile pic. When I update the profile pic in ProfileComponent the image changes in profile component but the changes are not reflected in navbar which is inside dashboard component.
To solve this I made communication service and I am emitting something whenever profile image is updated in Profile Component and DashboardComponent should listen to the change and if change exists then it should run the method to update the profile details which includes the image but its not working.

`updateProfilePic()` simply gets the profile details so if it is called again if there are changes then you can assign the property  new data.

```
{ 
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent, 
    canActivate: [AuthGuard], 
    children: [
        {
            path: '',
            component: DashboardHomeComponent,
        },
        {
            path: 'profile',
            component: ProfileComponent
        }
}
```

Dashboard component html

```
navbar code 
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Profile Component

```
profilePic: string;
profileDetail: any;
this.auth.updateProfilePic().subscribe((res: any)=>{
    this.profilepic = res.picLink;
    this.auth.updateProfileDetails().subscribe((res2)=>{
        this.profileDetail = res2;
        this.comService.emitChange();
    });
});
```

dashboard component

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.auth.updateProfileDetails().subscribe((res)=>{
        this.profileDetail = res;
    });
}

this.comService.changeEmitted$.subscribe(data => {
    // if there are changes then updateProfile method should be called
})
```

communation service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CommunicationService {

  constructor() { }
  private emitChangeSource = new Subject<any>();

    changeEmitted$ = this.emitChangeSource.asObservable();

    emitChange() {
        this.emitChangeSource.next();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your CommunicationService, I would suggest adding the following code

```
@Injectable()
export class CommunicationService {
    updated: Subscriber<boolean>;
    updateState: Observable<boolean> = new Observable((observer) => {
        this.updated = observer;
        this.updated.next(true);
    });
}
```

So when you want to notify the sidebar of a change, you'll just have to run `this.updated.next(true);`

Then, in the constructor of your SidebarComponent, you can subscribe to your Observable like so:

```
constructor(private communicationService: CommunicationService) {
    this.communicationService.updateState.subscribe(r => this.yourFunction());
}
```

Comment: It great but shouldn't `this.updated.next(true);` it be false false `this.updated.next(false);`  in the communication services file ? Because when i console.log `r` in my component its always true  I am using this like -  `this.communicationService.updateState.subscribe((r)=>{ console.log(r) if(r==true}{ only then run this code})`

Comment: Yes, you can pass any value that you want. Here, I set it to `boolean` so you can either pass `true` or `false`. But you can adapt the code to pass a string, or an object if you'd like.